# How to detetct inboud abandoned calls in a queue

Tags: asterisk

I want to detect incoming calls in a queue, abandoned before being answered by a member of the queue.

The queue_log file makes mention of these ones, so one approach would be to use this. But I'd like to handle this situation within my dialplan, with a command that issues a notification to a discord salon when such calls are detected.

I've tried to use the `h` extension :

```
exten = h,1,NoOp("hangup ! cause : ${HANGUPCAUSE}")
 same = n,GotoIf($[ ${HANGUPCAUSE} != 16 ]?done)
 same = n,system(/myTools/discord-notification "Missed call from ${CALLERID(num)}.")
 same = n(done),NoOp()
```

It works, but it does not differentiate answered calls from not answered / abandoned calls (they both issue a 16 hangup cause).

I've also tried to add a hangup handler using `hangup_handler_push` but it does not make any difference.

How can I detect such calls within the asterisk diaplan ?

Answer (score 0):

You have use queue_log(probably queue_log in mysql) or check QUEUESTATUS variable after end of call in top level of dialplan.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `QUEUESTATUS` , Asterisk Queue app sets another channel variable upon completition when a call is abandoned : `${ABANDONED}`.

I had to do it manually using this method :
Setting a shared channel variable abandoned to true before executing Queue app, then changing its value to false when the call is answered via Queue GoSub parameter.
And then you can catch its final value via h extension.

```
exten => _X!,1,Set(SHARED(ABANDONSTATUS,${CHANNEL(LINKEDID)})=true)
exten => _X!,n,Queue(${EXTEN},,,,,,,cust-Queue-GoSub)
exten => _X!,n,Set(SHARED(ABANDONSTATUS,${CHANNEL(LINKEDID)})=false)
exten => _X!,n,HangUp()

exten => h,1,NoOp(Abandoned : ${SHARED(ABANDONSTATUS,${CHANNEL(LINKEDID)})})


[cust-Queue-GoSub]

exten => s,1,Set(SHARED(ABANDONSTATUS,${CHANNEL(LINKEDID)})=false)
exten => s,n,Return()
```

Comment: Very strange solution. Too much work for info already in queue_log, doable by one line in config. Also without that shared and macros you will get in h-extension the same variable.

Comment: I had to do it manually because ${ABANDONED} variable was not documented back then. queuelog:im not a fan of flat file scan. Especially a file being hit with extremely high trafic. +im sure your usecase and mine are different. I had to detect the abandon in realtime and push to an external api. About the usage of sharedvariable: You are wrong. The custom variable is edited on both legs of the call, The caller's channel and the queue's extension/member who answered the call. so either variable inheritance while calls are bridged or shared variable on both channels based on LinkedIDPropagation

Comment: Sure no fan in flat scan. It is work with database.